# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

Tags: java

I'm parsing a doc and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:388)
    at CentroidGenerator$Centroid.averageLat(CentroidGenerator.java:403)
    at CentroidGenerator.getCentroids(CentroidGenerator.java:30)
    at CentroidGenerator.main(CentroidGenerator.java:139)
```

This is the part of code throwing the exception:

```
if (latitude!=null) {
    //if (!latitude.equals("null")) {
        String[] latValues = latitude.split(" ");
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < latValues.length; i++) {                
        sum = sum + Float.valueOf(latValues[i].trim()).floatValue();
    }
    latitude = Float.toString(sum / (float) latValues.length);
    //}
}
```

As you can see I've tried to check for "null" strings but even uncommenting the second if statement I get the same error.

thanks

Comment: Try adding a System.out.println(latValues[i].trim()) inside of your for loop, it may be possible that you're getting the null value as one of the latValues because of a spacing issue? And possibly one just after the if statement to print out latitude

Comment: Rollback to Revision 1: since the deleted comment is being addressed in the text and answers ("...the second if statement...")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe one of the values is "null" (for example, the string : `"123.4 null 5 null"`) not the first one, so I think a proper solution will be:

```
String[] latValues = latitude.split(" ");
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < latValues.length; i++) {              
    if (!latValues[i].equals("null"))
        sum = sum + Float.valueOf(latValues[i].trim()).floatValue();
}
latitude = Float.toString(sum / (float) latValues.length);
```

or instead, add try-cath inside the for loop and ignore values that are not numbers.

*EDIT*

As pointed in comments (Sualeh), it is better to use try / catch because today it's "null" tomorrow it's something else (i.e. double spaces...).

```
try {
sum = sum + Float.valueOf(latValues[i].trim()).floatValue();
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
// log e if you want...
}
```

Comment: you forgot to close the quote on the .equals("null")

Comment: To be 100% sure, it should be:  `if (!latValues[i].trim().equals("null"))`

Comment: This will still give exceptions if your string has multiple spaces in-between the number values.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid issues with strings like "1          2", with multiple spaces, which give null values, it is best to add a try-catch inside the loop, like this:

```
if (latitude != null) {
  String[] latValues = latitude.split(" ");
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < latValues.length; i++) {
    try {
      sum = sum + Float.valueOf(latValues[i].trim()).floatValue();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  latitude = Float.toString(sum / (float) latValues.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear that the problem is that you have an input line that has the characters `"null"` instead of one of the numbers.  But I don't think that ignoring the nulls is necessarily the right thing to do.

First, you need to figure out what those nulls really mean:

- Do they denote missing data-points (latitude values)?
- Are they a symptom of a bug in the code that captured the original latitude data?
- are they a symptom of a bug in the code that read the data from an input file / database?

Then maybe you need to track down the bug / bugs or adjust your processing to deal with the missing data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, it is very possible your `latValues[i].trim()` displays the value "`null`". I'm able to replicate your problem here:-

```
Float.valueOf("null");
```

Here's the stacktrace:-

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1301)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:375)
```

In another word, the value you have is not null, but it contains the word "null".

If you do `Float.valueOf(null);`, that actually gives you a `NullPointerException`, which is not what you have here.

Answer (score 0):

The call of the trim function is useless. If you really want to screen your input data to avoid the NumberFormatException you find the code in the [JavaDocs for Doubles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score -1):

The parseInt() and parseDouble() will error with NFE if passed with a null, space or blank string value. Once you have handled the null condition it will still fail with an empty string. Try adding a zero before the empty string like below. It maintains the integrity of calc as well:

Integer.parseInt("    ".trim())

to

Integer.parseInt( "0" + "    ".trim())